# Arduino Lego Robot

Tags: arduino-uno, robotics

I'm currently developing a Lego Robot, the mindstorm series to be specific. I want to replace the lego NXT brick with an arduino, maybe an intel galileo in the future. How do I establish connections from the arduino with the lego sensors? Also, I would like some input on any cool features that I can add to this robot. This robot is to be seen as a human companion. Thanks in advance.

An example of a sensor i would like to use is here : http://www.hitechnic.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=NIS1070

How do I interface this with an arduino?

Comment: Looks like they use I2C so you just have to look at the pinout and then hook it up to the I2C pins on the Arduino. http://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/connect-the-arduino-and-the-lego-mindstorms-together/

Answer (score 2):

Doing a quick search on google you can find a couple of shields designed for that purpose:

- [NXShield-Dx](http://www.robotshop.com/en/arduino-lego-mindstorms-shield-nxshield-d.html)
- [Bricktronics shield](https://store.wayneandlayne.com/products/bricktronics-shield-kit.html)

Second one is allows less motor connections but it's cheaper and has a [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024316.do) written by the designers